# Is it legal to publish an open source adapter to a closed source SDK?

Tags: publishing, software-development, intellectual-property

OSIsoft, LLC publishes an [SDK](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/1a02af4c-1bec-4804-a9ef-3c7300f5e2fc.htm) with their PI System, to which I wrote a python adapter. At this point it is for internal use in our company only, but I think it is potentially useful to other users of the OSIsoft PI System.

The adapter is pure python code that loads the .NET libraries from their installation directory, and so does not include the SDK itself. Under the assumption the company has no objection to publishing the code, is it legal to publish this under an open source license, and are there open source licenses that are incompatible with this?

Some links to license information of the software:

- [Copyright notice from AF SDK documentation](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/c3205f09-1ffb-4dd9-a9a9-b98ba26386ce.htm)
- [`C:\Program Files\PIPC\AF\LICENSE`](https://pastebin.com/7dc9NZpT)

Comment: Do you have a link to the license of this SDK?

Comment: I edited my question with some links to all license information I can find

Comment: Being this was built for internal use by your company (and yes, you count as your company) you should run this by the lawyers before publishing (and obviously get company approval to do so).

Comment: I know I need company approval, but I was wondering if it would be worth the trouble of getting approval, and whether it would technically be possible anyway to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

First: I am *not* a lawyer and this is *not* legal advice.

The first link you gave is the license for the documentation, not the SDK itself.

The second link has copyright information on the SDK iself and several components.

The SDK itself does not have any particular license according to the document, just this paragraph:

> This product is developed and copyrighted by OSIsoft, LLC. All rights reserved.

The components have MIT, Apache 2.0 and *MICROSOFT SOFTWARE SUPPLEMENTAL LICENSE TERMS*. None of them prohibits distribution of software which does use them.

Comment: Can I interprete this answer as "Yes, it is legal as long as you don't publish the SDK or claim copyright of the SDK"?

Comment: @hugovdberg I don't see anything which could prevent you from publishing it